# name of model instead of product_id value

Tags: python, api, odoo

I'm trying to get a product_id value from stock.quant, but instead I'm getting the name of the model and a list:

Here is the code:

```
class stock_quant(models.Model):

  _inherit = "stock.quant"
...some code...
prodID = product.id (the value is correct( 235 ), I have no problem there)
...some code...

for y in self.search([]):
              x=y.browse([(prodID)])
              
              _logger.info("myValue : " +str(x)) #so this value is displayed stock.quant(235,) but I
want to get only the 235 from this list.
```

So how to get a value from this Many2One?

Comment: `stock.quant(235,)` is a representation of a recordset, to get `235` in this example just use `x.id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
self.search([]):
```

you are writing a method in the `stock.quant` model, so in this method `self` is a object of `stock.quant`, so performing search on self results recordset of `stock.quant`, you are running the for loop for all the record of `stock.quant` model. so `y` is also a `stock.quant` record on each iteration of the loop, calling `y.browse()` will only result in another `stock.quant`. If you want to get `product.product` record, you have to either follow the `product_id` relation on `stock.quant` model, for example `y.product_id.id`, or fetch the model from registry, for example `self.env['product.product'].browse()`.

Comment: yes that's it. I resolved the problem like you, and I saw your answer after that))).thanks

Answer (score 2):

We can access model name from the *many2one* field using `_name` attribute.

For example,

> many2one_field_name._name